# openshift build config trigger

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-origin

we are using openshift 3.11, and having a buildConfig to trigger on github webhook, it works perfectly fine.

However I want to ignore certain files or directory or only trigger on certain directory, is that possible in openshift? Currently we are using Jenkinsfile strategy, one alternative is to have the logic in Jenkinsfile, but it doesnt seem like a clean way to do it

I have tried `contextDir`, but it just switch the working directory.